# SWIFT 5 compare date to know if is DAY or NIGHT

Tags: swift, date

I created a function that lets you know if the current time is day or night.
The problem is that even after sunset, the app tells me it's still daytime. So I think the IF conditions are not correct.
Can you help me find the solution?
The app uses the user's exact sunset and sunrise time. You have to compare them with the present time.
thank you

```
func actualTime(sunrise: Date, sunset: Date) {
    let date = Date()
    if (date < sunrise && date > sunset) {
        let nightTime = GrowingNotificationBanner(
            title: "Fuel Reserve AI: NIGHT-TIME".localised(),
            subtitle: "PlaneCalc applies nighttime fuel regulations".localised(),
            style: .warning
            
        )
        hapticWarning()
        nightTime.show()
    }
    else {
        let dayTime = GrowingNotificationBanner(
            title: "Fuel Reserve AI: DAY-TIME".localised(),
            subtitle: "PlaneCalc applies daytime fuel regulations".localised(),
            style: .success
        )
        dayTime.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some input values that produce the expected output and some that produce unexpected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition fails because of midnight, before midnight a time after sunset is not before sunrise for instance. So you need to include midnight in your comparisons

Check if now is between midnight and sunrise or after sunset to identify nighttime, otherwise it is daytime

```
func actualTime(sunrise: Date, sunset: Date) {
    let date = Date()
    let previousMidnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)
    if date >= previousMidnight && date < sunrise ||
        date > sunset {
        print("It's night")
    }
    else {
        print("It's day")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've a problem with 'current', the error is "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Calendar'.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisLrt sorry, a copy paste mistake. It’s been fixed now

Comment: thanks. I have just tested, the code works, but at Paris time, the application tells me that it is nighttime when it is 10:30 am.

Comment: Mr. Danielson, can I communicate with you by mail for example for another question of swift? thank you for your precious help.